# Как удалить часть строки по значению другой строки?

Tags: c++, linux

Имеется примерно такой код на C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string string1;
    string string2;
    /* Далее задаются строки (значения)
    Известно, что string1 является частью
    string2: т е все значение string1
    является частью значения string2 */
    return 0;
}
```

Что нужно? Поскольку **string1** - часть значения **string2**, нужно в **string2** заменить ту часть, что соответствует **string1**, и вывести новое значение **string2**. Я находил информацию про посимвольное удаление строк: *но мне нужно не это.* Как удалить часть значений одной переменной по значению другой, если они имеют сходные части? *Также, нужно строго сохранить тип **string**. На всякий случай скажу, что целевая система - Linux/Unix (чтобы не предлагали библиотеки WinAPI и т п)*

Comment: А если несколько раз встречается?

Comment: Чем нужно заменить?

Comment: Я уже разобрался. ```string2.replace(string2.find(string1),string1.length(),"new");```, где **string2.replace** - бОльшая строка, где меняем, **string2.find(string1)** - то, что мы меняем (в данном случае *string1*), **string1.length()** - длина заменяемой части, ну и **"new"** - то, на что мы меняем. Сама *string1* от этого не поменяется, меняется значение лишь *string2*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В классе `string` уже есть необходимые Вам функции, а именно:

- [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) - возвращает позицию первого символа подстроки в строке
- [`replace`](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) - меняет подстроку на другую

Вот пример поиска и замены всех подстрок в строке на другую:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string example = "It's charreally schartring of characters!";
    string old_substr = "char";
    string new_substr = "f";
    
    string::size_type pos = example.find(old_substr);
    while (pos != string::npos)
    {
        example.replace(pos, old_substr.size(), new_substr);
        pos = example.find(old_substr, pos + new_substr.size());
    }
    
    cout << example << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Но если Вы используете С++11 и выше, то это всё можно сделать в одну строку используя [`regex_replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string example = "It's charreally schartring of characters!";
    
    example = regex_replace(example, regex("char"), "f");

    cout << example << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `regex_replace()` — плохой совет в данном случае: во-первых, это тяжело, а, во-вторых, — строка может содержать спецсимволы…